# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{x^x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, logarithms

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{x^x}$$

I have assumed $$L=\lim_{h \to 0}h^{(h^h)}$$ taking $x=0+h$ where $h$ is a very small positive real number.

Now taking natural Log on both sides we get

$$\ln L=\lim_{h \to 0}h^h \ln h$$

How to proceed further

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0}x^x =1$$

Hence

$$\log \mathrm L=\lim_{x \to 0}x^x \log x=\lim_{x \to 0}1 \cdot \log x=-\infty$$

$$\implies \mathrm L=0$$

If you want to know why is $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}x^x =1$, rewrite it as $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}{e^{x \ln x}}$ and for that limit, [See this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470952/limit-of-x-log-x-as-x-tends-to-0)

Comment: sorry. But, why $\lim_{x\to 0}x^x=1$?

Comment: that is more clear for me, thanks.

Comment: @Julioenriquegodoymuñoz Welcome, glad I could help you! :-)

Comment: @JaideepKhare Sorry, I have a question $$\log L=\lim_{x \to 0}x^x \log x$$ after substituting $$x^{x}=1$$ we have to deal with logarithm $$\lim_{x\to0}=1 \cdot \log x=-\infty$$ but why the answer is not $$-\infty$$?  And why we can write so $$\log L=\lim_{x \to 0}x^x \log x$$

Comment: I ca understand why $$ \lim_{x\to0}x^{x}=1$$ but here we have $$ \lim_{x\to0}x^{x^{x}}$$ is the result the same?

Comment: @IlyaTelefus For your first comment, we have got $\log L =-\infty \implies L=e^{-\infty}$.Hence the limit is $$L=\frac{1}{e^{\infty}}=0$$ I don't understand what do you want to say in your second comment.