# Showing $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} xy \log(x^2+y^2) = 0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

First I let $x=r\cos \theta, y = r\sin \theta$ and so limit

$$\lim_{r\to 0} r^2\sin2\theta \log(r)$$

Now, in region $0<x<1$, $\log(x) < 1/x$ 
$$|r^2\sin 2\theta \log (r) - 0| < |r\sin 2\theta| \le |r| < \delta < \epsilon$$

So limit exist if $\delta < \epsilon$ and limit is 0.

---

Other way, I used L hospital, I don't know if we can apply, but I wrote $r^2 \log r$ as $\log(r) / (r^{-2})$ which again gave 0.

Comment: Your proof assumes both $x$ and $y$ got to $0$.  It is easy to show that the limit is $0$ even if only one variable goes to $0$, but your proof does not apply there, since $r$ does not go to $0$.  In this case you need to use $sin2\theta \to 0$, since $\theta \to 0$ or $\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @herb Sorry i dont understand why we use $\sin 2\theta \to 0$

Comment: Of course $r\to 0$ here, while $\sin 2\theta$ does not even need to converge. I don't understand the comment made by @herbsteinberg.

Comment: $r \to 0$ requires both $x$ and $y \to 0$.  My comment was about the case where only one variable $\to 0$, but the other did not.  In that situation $\theta \to 0$ or $\to \frac{\pi}{2}$, so $sin2\theta \to 0$.

Comment: @jeea Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$xy \log(x^2+y^2) =(x^2+y^2)\log(x^2+y^2)\cdot \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\to 0$$

indeed since $t=x^2+y^2\to 0$

$$(x^2+y^2)\log(x^2+y^2)=t\log t\to 0$$

and since $x^2+y^2\ge 2xy$

$$0\le \left|\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right| \le \frac12$$

Comment: How to show $t\log t \to 0$ as $t\to 0$ ??

Comment: It is a standard limit, to show that we can use l’Hopital (I don’t like) or (better) let $t=e^{-x}\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ then $t\log t=-\frac x{e^x}\to 0$.

Comment: Again how to show $\frac{x}{e^x} \to 0$ ? I needed epsilon delta!

Comment: @jeea That also a standard limit, we can use again l'Hopita (I don't like) or (better) use that eventually $e^x>x^2 \implies \frac x{e^x}<\frac1x \to 0$.

Comment: @jeea Before solving multivariable limits you should have a strong base with those foundamental limits for functions of one variable and sequences, if you have doubts on that revise them.

Comment: a very good advice, I was out of time due to college examinations!

Comment: Here on MSE you can find easily the way to revise them! Bye

Comment: Of course, one could use $|\log(x^2+y^2)|\le \frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and forgo appeal to the limit $\lim_{t\to0}t\log(t)=0$.

Answer (score 6):

> **I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that is direct and follows from a pair of elementary inequalities only.   To that end we proceed.**

Using $\color{blue}{|\log(x)|<\frac1{\sqrt{x}}}$ for $x\le 1$ along with $\color{red}{|xy|\le \frac12(x^2+y^2)}$, we have for any given $\varepsilon>0$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\color{red}{xy}\color{blue}{\log(x^2+y^2)}\right|&\le \color{red}{\frac12 (x^2+y^2)}\color{blue}{\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}\\\\
&=\frac12 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\\\
&<\varepsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta=2\varepsilon$.

And we are done!

Answer (score 1):

More easily, $lim_{r\rightarrow 0}rlog(r)=0$, we deduce that $lim_{r\rightarrow 0}r^2log(r)=0$ since $|sin(\theta)|\leq 1$, the result follows.

[Limit of $x \log x$ as $x$ tends to $0^+$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470952/limit-of-x-log-x-as-x-tends-to-0)