# Limit of $\lim _{\left(x,y\right)\to \left(0,0\right)}\left(\left(xy\right)\ln \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, logarithms

I want to calculate limit of  $\lim _{\left(x,y\right)\to \left(0,0\right)}\left(\left(xy\right)\ln \left(x^2+y^2\right)\right)$ using Squeeze theorem or using definition of limit. please help

Comment: Some context or your own attempt would help us help you. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} xy \log(x^2+y^2) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899091/showing-lim-x-y-to-0-0-xy-logx2y2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that $|xy|\le \frac12(x^2+y^2)$ so that

$$\left|xy\log(x^2+y^2)\right|\le (x^2+y^2)\left|\log\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\right|$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: $|\ln{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|$ is defined when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ ? How do I do then?

Comment: Note that $\log(x)\le \sqrt{x}$.  So for $x<1$, $|\log(x)|\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.  Now just replace $x$ with $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: thanks, i still don't understand, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ not defined when $x \to 0$

Comment: could you help me please

Comment: You're right.  $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$ is not defined.  But $\lim_{x\to0} x/\sqrt{x}=0$ is defined.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you again for your help

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: what are the final inequalities to proof  the limit?

Comment: $|(x^2+y^2)\log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})|\le \frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac12\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$